# Batch file for copying a folder by checking its presence

Tags: batch

I am a new user.

I want to copy a folder containing some files into another directory.

1. I have to check whether the destination directory exist or not.
   a. If exists then prompt for user input - want to copy into existing or not.
   b. If does not exist then ask the user whether to create the new folder and copy.

I tried this but though the folder exist or not it is creating the folder by itself n here i m using XCOPY.
Can u pls help me.
Thank you.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried something like: xcopy srcfolder "n:/folder1/path1/path2", whr path1 is the name of d folder which is to created if and only if it does not exists. Path2 is the actual folder to be copied. Actual script i wil send u on Monday as it is in office pc.

Answer (score 0):

Use xcopy

It'll ask you whether the destination is file or directory in cases where the destination folder does not exist.

```
@echo off

xcopy "fullsourcepathfolder" "destinationxpath" /s /y
```

Do not ignore the full path even if it is your current working directory.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working at my end. But if i use XCOPY /E "%PROJNAME%" "P:\Archive\Profiles\%destinationName%\%PROJNAME%" though the directory (destinationName) exists or not it is copying the files into it. where destinationName is taken by user input which has to be verified that it already exists or not.